# What is "theae folium"?

Tags: botany, pharmacology, food, ethnobiology

I wanted to buy black tea at a pharmacy and the pharmacist told me that russian tea is actually black tea so I bought it instead.It's made out of theae folium leaves and for some reason I can't find anything about that plant on the internet and I know that black tea is made out of camelia sinensis leaves, not theae folium.Can anyone tell me what is this plant and is it really russian tea (i found somewhere that russian tea is made from a different plant) and what is this "Russian" tea good for?

Answer (score 3):

Judging by this image in wikipedia, I would say Theae folium is another name (probably a name in another language) for *Camellia sinensis*

[image]

Comment: It's Latin for "Tea leaf".

Comment: @CactusWoman, the answer is "tea leaf". Camellia sinensis is a flower and here  is just an example of tea. there are others theae folium, not related to this flower.

Comment: _Camellia sinensis_ is the botanical name for the plant whose leaves are used for the beverage commonly known as _tea_ in English (green tea, black tea, etc.).  The plant of course has a flower in the normal course of its growth (as well as leaves, seeds, roots, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If the labelling is correct, this should be *Camellia sinensis*, the plant that produces black tea, green tea, etc. (although not many things that are commonly referred to or marketed as herbal teas).

*Thea* is the [original genus name](http://www.tropicos.org/Name/31600166) given by Linnaeus to the species we now call *Camellia sinensis*.

There's an old pharmacy tradition of specialized latin terminology for plant medicines. These will indicate the plant and also often the [plant part](http://abc.herbalgram.org/site/PageServer?pagename=Terminology#Plant%20Parts). In this tradition, plants are often indicated with different terminology than modern scientific names. Here's a 19th century pharmacy textbook (Parrish and Weigand) explaining why:
[image]

And here's the same source discussing the naming of plants parts (as CactusWoman mentions, in this case *folium* = leaf):
[image]

You still see this terminology around in some places (some European texts and occasionally translations of Traditional Chinese Medicine preparations), but it definitely has an 'old-fashioned' feel from the perspective of a botanist.

---

[Parrish and Weigand 1884 *A Treatise on Pharmacy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3_BCAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA61&ots=JbXCcClswV&dq=latin%20pharmacy%20names%20radix&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1434/5114191089_e95dd1f1c9.jpg is where I first encountered this form of antiquated nomenclature (in traditional Chinese medicine)